# Pull ContentDocuments through the API

Tags: rest-api, api, administration, contentdocument

We are trying to pull all of the ContentDocuments out through the API as an admin user, but we are having issues.  Unlike the UI, the APIs do not allow listing all the records in Content, even for users with the Modify-All-Data permission.
Is there any way to do that without manually add the API user as a member of all the folders? 
It would be great if we could pull all the ContentDocuments through the API.

Comment: Can you add the REST Endpoint API URL you are trying ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - it seems that the list of all records in Content isn't exposed to the Admin user via the API. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct it is not exposed

Comment: is there any workaround? Is there a way to add the admin to all the libraries?

Comment: Seems like an idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfXGAA0

Comment: How many libraries you have ?You may manually do it via UI if its not in 1000's .